# How to prevent child loader from being fired if not rendered in React Router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

## Background

Now, I'm implementing Protected Routes using React Router V6.

My current routing looks like the follow code:

```
<Route>
  <Route path="/" element={<Navigate to={"/home"} />} />
  <Route element={<PrivateRoutes />}>
    <Route
      path="/*"
      element={<App />}
      loader={loadApp}
      errorElement={<ErrorPage />}
    >
      <Route path="home" element={<InputForm />} />
      <Route path="review" element={<Review />} loader={loadReview} />
      <Route path="library" element={<Library />} loader={loadLibrary} />
    </Route>
  </Route>
  <Route path="account/*" loader={loadCSRFToken}>
    <Route path="register" element={<Register />} />
    <Route path="login" element={<Login />} />
  </Route>
</Route>
```

Inside the `PrivateRoutes` component, I'm checking if the current user is authenticated by using `useEffect`

```
export const PrivateRoutes = () => {
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    let checkAuth = async () => {
      console.log("CHECK AUTH");
      try {
        let response = await axios.get(API_CHECK_AUTH);
        console.log(response);
        setIsAuthenticated(true);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    };
    checkAuth();
  }, []);

  return isAuthenticated ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/account/login" />;
  // return null;
};
```

## Problem

The problem here is that: when I return `null` or `Navigate to another page` in the `PrivateRoutes`, meaning `App` is not even rendered, I expect the loader function, which fetches necessary data, should not be called. However, it turns out that the `loadApp` is called first even before `useEffect` is called if the path is related to `APP`. Even though I had security measure to block requests in `loadApp`, it's still really odd that the loader function is called even when the component is not rendered.

Is there a possible way to call loader only when rendered, or a better way to implement Protected Routes that avoids this problem?

[image]

Comment: Route loaders are called ***before*** the routes load, so `loadApp` is called prior to  both any of the protected routes ***and*** `PrivateRoutes` mounting. The idea behind loaders is that they fetch data ***then*** mount the route to provide the fetched data You may just need to do an auth check in `loadApp` if it matters there. You might also consider [deferred loading](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/guides/deferred). Depending on what the loader needs to do thought this might be a little dicey.